# How to get first child of an item in content tree?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-query, renderfield

I am trying to get only one item under a specific page in the content tree using a query in variant. I tried `query:.//*` but it gets all children under that item. I only need the first one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Maximal number of results` field for this:

[image]

Comment: Use `./*` instead of `.//*` if you want to avoid getting all items recursively but only children from the first level.